# scrolling not working for views inside tabbar application

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have created a `tabBar` application, it has two tabs one `tableView` with detail items and another simple `UIView` with a `UILabel`. I added `scrollView` to `detailViewController` and put all UI items under `scrollView` to get scrolling. I connected the `scrollView` using `outlet` to my detail view and set the following in `detailViewController`

```
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width,scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

However detail view is not scrolling, its screen is locked. why?

Answer (score 0):

For a UIScrollView, you want the frame to be the size you want it to appear on the screen, and the content size to be the size it will be able to scroll through. So, for scrolling to work properly, you must have the content size set to larger than the view's size in one dimension or the other.

Comment: Yes, I have already taken care of the size dimensions. Scroll views size is larger than other items, it didn't get to work. It seems the screen is locked horizontally  and vertically no movement is happening when I move on the screen.

Comment: did you get any resolution for the above issue